# Updating a dictionary dynamically with foreach

Tags: c#, dictionary

When trying to update a Dictionary with the following:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in dict)
{
dict[pair.Key] = "Hello";
}
```

And exception is thrown. Is there any way to dynamically update the dictionary WITHOUT making any kind of key or value backups?

EDIT!!!!!! View code. I realized that this portion was actually doable. The real case is this. I thought they would be the same, but they are not.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in dict)
    {
    dict[pair.Key] = pair.Key + dict[pair.Key];
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Any reason why you're not iterating over the keys?

```
foreach(var key in dict.Keys)
{
    dict[key] = "Hello";
}
```

Comment: You are right, but my error was occurring from reusing dictionary in the looping.

Comment: @Sekkt Just use `dict[key] = key + dict[key];`

Comment: @Sekkt - Don't use foreach loop if you want to iterate the dictionary itself and modify its contents without using `ToList`.

Answer (score 2):

You can either loop over the dictionary (you need to use `ToList` because you can't change a collection that is being looped over in a foreach loop)

```
foreach(var key in dict.Keys.ToList())
{
    dict[key] = "Hello";
}
```

or you can do it in one line of LINQ as you're setting the same value to all the keys.

```
dict = dict.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => "Hello");
```

**Updated question**

```
foreach (var key in dict.Keys.ToList())
{
    dict[key] = key + dict[key];
}
```

and the LINQ version

```
dict = dict.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x =>  x.Key + x.Value);
```

If you want to avoid using `ToList`, you can use `ElementAt` so that you can modify the collection directly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dict.Count; i++) 
{
   var item = dict.ElementAt(i);
   dict[item.Key] = item.Key + item.Value;
}
```